# Get nested class from Roslyn CompilationUnitSyntax

Tags: c#, typescript, code-generation, roslyn

I am using Roslyn to parse som C# files, in order to generate TypeScript typings.

```
var source = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(pathToCSharpFile);
var tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(source);
var root = (CompilationUnitSyntax) tree.GetRoot();
```

I walk the tree recursively from the root to get information about properties, fields and nested classes.

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class Foo
    {
        public Bar BarProp { get; set; }

        public Baz BazProp { get; set; }

        public class Bar
        {
        }
    }
}
```

The TypeScript defenition for this has to become:

```
interface Foo {
    barProp: Foo.Bar;
    bazProp: Baz;
}

namespace Foo {
    interface Bar {
    }
}
```

What eludes me, is how to determine that the type of BarProp is a nested class, in order to specify the type for barProp correctly in the TypeScript definition.

Is this information available when using PropertyDeclarationSyntax, FieldDeclarationSyntax and ClassDeclarationSyntax, or do I need to use a different approach to infer the correct types?

Comment: Actually not, using `PropertyDeclarationSyntax` and etc. you can retrieve semantic info about the `BazProp` type, but this info can't tell you that this type is nested or not. When you walk the tree recursively you should store the current declaring type and when you again meet type declaration you will know that is it nested or not.

Comment: You (mostly) need the semantic model (and a compilation) to retrieve full type information.